# SQL: select similar and rows that don't exist in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

TABLE1:

```
+-----------+----------+
|    CODE   |  TYPEID  |
+-----------+----------+
| 441       |  mn014   |
| 223       |  mn014   |
| 224       |  mn014   |
| 655       |  mn089   |
| 854       |  mn089   |
| 449       |  mn032   |
+-----------+----------+
```

TABLE2:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| CODE      | TAKENDTE | RTURNDTE |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 441       | 25/08/14 | 01/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 03/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 01/02/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 655       | 25/08/14 | 07/01/15 |
| 854       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 449       | 25/08/14 | 06/01/15 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

I want to select all codes of the typeid mn014 that either don't exist in the second table or are NOT NULL in the RTURNDTE column in all instances they exist in table 2

I was thinking something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.CODE
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2

ON T1.CODE=T2.CODE
WHERE TYPEID='mn014' AND (RTURNDTE IS NOT NULL OR T2.CODE IS NULL)
```

That didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can phrase this as a `NOT EXISTS` -- with a filter on `table2`.  You are looking for records in table 1 that have no record in table 2 with a `NULL` return date (if I understand the question correctly).

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where typeid = 'mn014' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.rturndte is null
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'CODE'
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t1.code = t2.code
)
OR 
NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'NULLABLE'
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.code = t1.code
    AND t2.RTURNDTE IS NULL
)
AND t1.typeid = 'mn014'
```